# Area51 account not showing up in my accounts tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-accounts

[My Area51 account](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/28610/?tab=accounts) is not currently showing up on my accounts list here (nor on [English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/8816/monica-cellio?tab=accounts)).  I noticed this Friday afternoon here (but not on English.SE) and figured it was a passing glitch, but apparently not.  As you can see if you look at my Area51 account, it's not that the accounts have somehow become disassociated; Area51 knows about all of my accounts.

My rep on Area51 is currently 376, so it should be showing up between these two on my list:

[image: part of my accounts list]

I just noticed that my accounts page says it's listing 12 accounts but only lists 11, so it appears that other accounts know about Area51 but aren't displaying it.

Is this a bug?  A transient, two-day glitch?

Comment: I reproduced this on Judaism.SE for both of our accounts. Also note that it is always visible on the mobile site

Comment: FWIW, same for me: my accounts are associated, but my A51 account doesn't show on my list here at meta.JLL or on JLL, EL&U, Math, or meta.Math, but is included in the sum total.

Comment: Other problems with the account tab: it's showing week old rep counts for only one of my sites.

Comment: Listed at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53927 as [meta-tag:status-completed] from more than a year ago. Does anyone know for certain that area51 accounts *were* listed on JLL/meta.JLL "accounts" pages *until* ~2 days ago?

Comment: Ah! Found it! This question is a **duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122744**. (Not that this should be closed. I'm just saying you might want to check there for helpful comments/answers.)

Comment: @HodofHod, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122829.

Comment: @msh210, I know that my Area51 account was listed here until two days ago.

Comment: @msh210 thanks for the link to the other question.  I'll watch that too.

Comment: What should happen to this question now that it's also been found on (and linked to from) meta.SO?  There's more information here than there; should I edit all this into the question there and close this one?

Comment: @MonicaCellio, the SE folks keep telling us that the "child metas" (like meta.Judaism.SE) are just as good as MSO, so I see no reason to close this and merge the info thither. Obviously, you're welcome to if you like.

Comment: @msh210, it's fixed now, but I can't tag this status-completed.  (I also can't accept my own answer for 2 days; is that by design for meta sites?  On main it makes sense...)

Answer (score 1):

This is now fixed (see [meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122846/162102)).

Comment: Did you check it works for you also? (It does for me.)

Comment: @msh210 yes I did.

Comment: @msh210 I'd say that resolving this problem has been [completed](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed)!